# Largest common multiple equal or lower than max

Tags: r

I made this small and easy function that returns the largest common multiple of the elements of `ms` that is equal to or lower than `max`:

```
LCMLthan = function(ms,max) {
    ms = sort(ms, decreasing =TRUE)
    max2 = c()
    for (m in ms)
    {
        max2=append(max2,m*floor(max/m))
    }
    max2=min(max2)
    while (T)
    {
        maxOld = max2
        for (m in ms)
        {
            if(max2%%m!=0){
                max2 = max2 - 1
                break
            }
        }
        if (maxOld==max2){
            return (max2)
        }
    }
}

### Examples
LCMLthan(c(3,5),52)
[1] 45
LCMLthan(c(178,124,17),520000)
[1] 375224
```

Looking at my code, it feels like there must have a cleaner and more efficient way to code this function. There is also probably a better way to name it too.

Comment: Largest common multiple is necessarily a multiple of a least common multiple. So the solution is to find the least common multiple `lcm` and compute the result as `lcm * (max / lcm)` (integer division assumed). I don't know [tag:r] to give a proper review.

Comment: As mentioned there's a better algorithm.  To review your original algorithm I see two points: 1) the sorting is unnecessary. 2) the update of max2 = max2-1 is very inefficient - you could save a lot by updating it the way you calculate the initial max2 instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looping is generally not recommended in R.
And it's not really needed here.

As [@vnp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/40480/vnp) pointed out in a comment,
all you need is simply calculate the least common multiple of the values in the input vector, let's call it `lcm`, and apply the formula `lcm * (max // lcm)` (with integer division).

The [pracma](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/pracma/docs/lcm) library already has an implementation of the least common multiple. If installing that library is not an option for you, you can use this instead:

```
gcd <- function(a, b) {
  stopifnot(is.numeric(a), is.numeric(b))
  if (a > b) gcd(b, a)
  else if (a == 0) b
  else gcd(b %% a, a)
}

Lcm <- function(a, b) {
  stopifnot(is.numeric(a), is.numeric(b))
  a / gcd(a, b) * b
}
```

To calculate the least common multiples for a vector of numbers:

```
Lcm.many = function(values) {
  stopifnot(values)
  if (length(values) == 2) {
    Lcm(values[1], values[2])
  } else {
    Lcm.many(c(Lcm(values[1], values[2]), tail(values, -2)))
  }
}
```

Then with these helper functions the implementation of your function becomes much simpler:

```
LCMLthan = function(ms, max) {
  lcm <- Lcm.many(ms)
  lcm * (max %/% lcm)
}
```

#### Update

As [@flodel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/16479/flodel) pointed out in a comment,
there's actually no need for `Lcm.many` at all,
the call to it can be simply replaced with `Reduce(Lcm, ms)`:

```
LCMLthan = function(ms, max) {
  lcm <- Reduce(Lcm, ms)
  lcm * (max %/% lcm)
}
```

Comment: Not tested but I bet you can do `lcm <- Reduce(Lcm, ms)` as a replacement to implementing a `Lcm.many`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, updated my answer, thanks a lot!